# Android MediaPlayer not stopping by clicking another button

Tags: java, android, button, audio, media-player

When you click on two buttons you hear two sounds. How can i Stop the first sound and play the second sound or when i play the first sound, that the second sound stops? How can i create this? Here my Media PLayer

```
final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        JSONArray songs = (JSONArray) response.getJSONArray("songs");
                        for ( int i = 0; i < songs.length(); i++) 
                        {
                            // Create LinearLayout
                           audio = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_AUDIO) ;
                           String chanson = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString("title") ;
                           String duration = songs.getJSONObject(i).getString(TAG_DURATION) ;

                           LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                           ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                           final TextView txtchanson = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                           txtchanson.setText(chanson);
                           txtchanson.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
                           TextView txtduration = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                           txtduration.setText(duration);

                           final Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
                           final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
                           mp.setAudioSessionId(i+1);

                           mp.setDataSource(audio); 
                           mp.prepare();

                           btn.setId(i+1);
                           btn.setTypeface(ionicons);
                           btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                           btn.setLayoutParams(params);

                           final int index = i;
                           mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
                             {

                                 public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
                                 {

                                     btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                                 }
                             });

                             btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) 
                                    {


                                        Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                                "Clicked Button Index :" +  btn.getId(), 
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        boolean b = false ;
                                        if ( b == false )

                                        {

                                            //txtchanson.setTextColor(R.color.green);
                                            mp.start();
                                            btn.setText(getString(R.string.pause_str));
                                            b = true;

                                        }

                                        else //if (btn.getText().equals( getString(R.string.pause_str)))
                                        {
                                            mp.pause();
                                            btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                                            //txtchanson.setTextColor(R.color.gray);
                                            b = false;

                                        }
                                    /*  else if (b == true )
                                        {
                                            btn.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
                                            mp.pause();
                                        }*/
                                    }
                                });


                             ll.addView(btn);
                             ll.addView(txtchanson);
                             ll.addView(txtduration);

                             lm.addView(ll);  

                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place your `boolean b = false ;` line out of the onClick method it should be as a global variable, because on every click, when you go to the onClick method, your `b` variable gets a false value and it never steps into the else clause of your if-else statement. Everything else is okay.

Comment: the second click the second button does not work, I want when I click on the play button first and when I click on another button the first is paused and the second plays !!

Comment: you have only one button, so on the first click of this button, you should start the player, and on the second click of the same button, you should stop it. Did you try it with my suggestion?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and its not working, the error that I had is that when I click the first time the song plays but when I click the second time on the second button its not working

Comment: which one is your second button? I see only this one `final Button btn = new Button(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: i create button dynamiclly loook my loop for for ( int i = 0; i < songs.length(); i++) 
                        {

Comment: aha I understand... so you can make your MediaPlayer global (not for every single song - it is not necessary) and change your `if(b==false){...}else...` with a proof if the player is playing + changing your song on new button clicked
`if(mp.isPlaying())
{
    mp.pause();
}
else
{
   ....
    mp.start();
}`

Comment: But i have multipe songs ,   
I tried your suggestion and its not working, :(